# design breaking while rendering as PDF in VF page

Tags: visualforce, lightning, css, knowledge

I am having a design issue when I try to download/view a ID card kind of template as a PDF. I have a template of an ID card as knowledge article and a View/download button near that. so the ID card is displaying perfectly with correct alignment and design on web page, but when user clicks the view/download button the design and alignments are breaking here and there.
Is there any way to get the same design as knowledge article to render as PDF?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I note you tagged this with "css". Be aware that (in my experience) CSS is entirely ignored when generating PDFs and that you can only do this via the use of inline style attributes.